# Same rewriting rules on multiple pages in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have two links on two different pages:
1: `destinations.php?country=america` which I want changed into `example.com/america`
2: `cheap-flights.php?city=paris` which I want changed into `example.com/paris`

my .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ destinations.php?country=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ cheap-flights.php?city=$1 [L]
```

The problem is that only the first rule is working. I researched this problem and I found multiple rules not worked on same directory.

Comment: The problem here is that from a URL it's not possible to tell whether we're working on a city or country. Your first RewriteRule will match both `/america` and `/paris` and will treat both as countries for the purpose of locating the right PHP file to execute. The second RewriteRule will never be executed since the first will already have rewritten the URL and it also has a [L] last flag to prevent this. Even if you removed the [L] flag, it wouldn't help the flawed logic here at all. Either find a new URL format, or rewrite both to the same PHP file to distinguish countries from cities.

Comment: then what is the solution for that problem

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the URL formats:
`example.com/country/america` and `example.com/city/paris`.
Then adjust the RewriteRules like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^country/([^/\.]+)/?$ destinations.php?country=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^city/([^/\.]+)/?$ cheap-flights.php?city=$1 [L]
```

If that is not possible, you can mix countries and cities by using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ cityorcountry.php?cityorcountry=$1 [L]
```

Then from within that PHP file you can check the parameter against a small list of known countries in an array. Then if it's a country in the array, treat it as a country, if not in the array, treat it as a city. Or perhaps consult a third party with the keyword to decide whether its a country, city, or neither before deciding which script to execute.

Comment: Should i need any chages in php code or i have to move my files in a folder by making example.com/country/america ??

Comment: Do the files destinations.php and cheap-flights.php exist on your server? Or is example.com a different domain from your server?

Comment: its on the same server

Comment: destinations.php and cheap-flights.php are on the root directory of server

Comment: Then you shouldn't be getting a 404 page. To be clear, the way `RewriteRule`s work is that any URL the user types into their browser, first the domain name is looked up against a DNS to get the ip address of your server. Then your server maps the directory on the server associated with the domain. Then only is the .htaccess file in the web root is run. At this point, the server still doesn't know if `example.com/country/america` is a valid directory or file. Then the .htaccess RewriteRule will rewrite it to: `example.com/destinations.php?country=america`. Finally your PHP file is ran.

Comment: You're not supposed to create a folder country or city. That is what RewriteRule does for you, it catches all URLS, includes 404 non-existent folder URLS, matching a pattern on the left `^country/([^/\.]+)/?$` and rewriting the request to the existing file on the right; `destinations.php?country=$1`. Does `example.com/destinations.php?country=america` load if you attempt to open the link directly or is it giving you a 404 error?

Comment: my php code for destination.php files is : <a href="'.country.'"> '.$country.'</a> and cheap flight is: <a href="'.city.'"> '.$city.'</a>

Comment: <a href="'.$country.'"> '.$country.'</a> i am just sending the variable in ahref  that is <a href="'.$country.'"> '.$country.'</a>